# Creating Hadoop java example

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I know this question has been asked before but I cannot seem to figure it out.  I have a single node cluster setup using hadoop that is working correctly.  I am trying to compile the WordCount.java example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      int sum = 0;
      while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next().get();
      }
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
  }
}
```

I've installed hadoop-2.2.0 to /usr/local/hadoop/ but I cannot for the life of me figure out what .jar files I need to add in eclipse to import the org.apache.hadoop files.  I hardly ever use Java or eclipse but I've copied every .jar file in the hadoop home folder to a lib folder in my eclipse workspace and added the external .jars in the project settings.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to supply the input and output details, plus maybe other things (depending on how much you have done beyond the sample code you submitted).

Here is a more detailed tutorial:

- [Running Hadoop from Eclipse Kepler](http://letsdobigdata.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/running-hadoop-mapreduce-application-from-eclipse-kepler/)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was using that tutorial but when I go to my /usr/local/hadoop and /usr/local/hadoop/lib there are 0 .jar files in either directory. http://www.interior-dsgn.com/apache/hadoop/core/stable/hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz is the mirror I used to download it.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. In 2.2.0 the .jar files are in the /shared/hadoop/ folder